# Raspberry pi Encoder with python not plotting graph showing RPM -OPEN

Tags: python, matplotlib, raspberry-pi

I have tried many times but unable to  get what could be the issue in this
I have attached the raspberry pi 4 with hall effect encoder using only X1 decoding for encoder, PPR is 160, and also have include dynamic model but unable to execute it properly to run on open loop. I m also filttering the singnal by usiign low pass filter, its working fine with PID but unable to get results on simple Open loop system.

```
   import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    import numpy as np
    import time
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
    from time import sleep
    import random
    import sensormotion as sm
    from motor_model import motor
    from scipy.integrate import odeint
    #Defining GPIO PINS
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) #Sensor Input Aout
    GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT) #PWM PIN
    GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.OUT) #Left Direction
    GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.OUT) #Right Direction
    #Initial Setup Setup
    simulationTime = 10 #Total Simulation time for the Motor
    samplingTime = 0.01 #Sampling time for each tick count
    setPoint = 500  #Desire RPM
    count = 0   #counting the ticks of the motor
    refperiod = 5 #PWM period  time taken by PWM to complete one cycle.
    pwmResolution = 4096 # 4096 steps Because of raspberry pi 4 has 12bit resolution has factor 0.00024
    simulationTime = int(1000 / 24 * simulationTime) #converting Raspberry pi  from resolution factor 0.00024
    refperiod = int(1000 / 24 * refperiod)
    encoderCount = 55 #assuming Pulse Per Revolution here
    scale = 1 / samplingTime  #frequency of the tick count
    pwmOut = GPIO.PWM(18, 1 / samplingTime)  # GPIO.PWM ([pin],frequency]) here 100Hz when simulation time is 0.01
    try:
       while True:
    ##########Couting the encoder up pulses
            def counterup(channel):
                global count
                if GPIO.input(channel) == 1:
                    count += 1
                else:
                    count += 0
                    print(count)
            #Enocder ticks count to RPM conversion
            def speedConvert():           
                speedDC = count * 60 * scale / encoderCount
                print(speedDC)
                return speedDC        
    ####  MotorDirection Setting
            def motorDirection(direction):
                # Counter Clockwise Direction
                if direction == 'ccw': 
                    GPIO.output(27, 1)
                    GPIO.output(22, 0)
                # Clockwise Direction
                elif direction == 'cw': 
                    GPIO.output(27, 0)
                    GPIO.output(22, 1)
                else: # Stop the Motor
                    GPIO.output(27, 0)
                    GPIO.output(22, 0)
            motorDirection ('cw')        
            #intializing arrays for saving values
            y = np.array([])    
            t = np.linspace(0,20)
            for x in range (0,20):
                count = 0
                GPIO.add_event_detect(17, GPIO.RISING, callback = counterup)
                sensorRead = speedConvert()
                pwmOut.start(50)
                y = np.append(y,sensorRead)
                sleep(samplingTime) #Updating Error after each sampling time that is 0.01 or 1 ms
                  #Intialzing count here for the update 
            #If all the above logic fails motor will not run
             else :
                 pwmOut.start(0)
    ####################Singal Filtering#############################
    # #-------------------------LOW PASS FILTER
    #    #     t = np.multiply(t, 24 / 1000)
    #         sampling_rate = 1000
    #         #Building  a butterworth filter with specified parameters.
    #         #                            Frequency, sampling rate, filter type, filter order
    #         b, a = sm.signal.build_filter(5.7, sampling_rate, 'low', filter_order=1)
    #         y_f = sm.signal.filter_signal(b, a, y)  # Filtering Encoder Data
    #      
    ##################Dc Motor Model Plot# #################################################
    # Parameter for Dc motor
    #         J = 0.01  # [kg.m^2]   Moment of inertia of motor
    #         b = 0.1  # [N.m.s]    Damping ratio of mechanical system
    #         K = 0.01  # constant Ke= Kt = K
    #         R = 1  # [ohm]      Electrical resistance
    #         L = 0.5  # [H]   Electrical inductance
    #                
    #         y0 = [ 0,0,0]
    #         ym= odeint(motor, y0, t )     
    ######################Comparative results of Low pass and Orignal Signal#################     
            print(y)       
            plt.figure(figsize=(6, 5))
    #         plt.plot(t, ym[:, 2], color='b', linewidth = 2,label = 'Simulated Result')
            plt.plot(t, y, 'k' , linewidth = 0.3 ,label='Encoder Output')
    #         plt.plot(t, y_f, color='g', linewidth = 2,label = 'Low Pass Filter')
            plt.title("Comparative Results of Reference Signal, Simulated Output and Encoder Output with Low Pass Filter")
            plt.xlabel('Time [s]')
            plt.ylabel('Speed (RPM [rad/s]')
            plt.legend(loc='upper right')
            plt.grid()
            plt.show()
            #after Completting the loop
            motorDirection('stop')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("program interrupted")
    finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```